# Need help with fonts in latex: output too dim

Tags: pdf, latex, fonts

I have a problem where all fonts come out too dim. Is there any thing I can do to get a different
look and feel from the pdfs?

My tex file looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}`
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\rfoot{Raval, Ketan R -13223}

\textwidth 15.5cm
\topmargin -1cm
\parindent 0cm
\textheight 26.5cm
\parskip 1mm


\begin{document}

\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontshape{\shapedefault}
\selectfont
```

So how can I improve my overall look and feel of the pdf?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean it prints lightly? Or the fontface is too thin? Or your text is light gray for some reason? I don't see anything that should produce anything too out of the ordinary, from a cursory overview, so you might want to clarify.

Comment: I would suggest using the fontenc and lmodern packages to get Type1 fonts, which tend to work better:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

Comment: My guess is that Type 3 (bitmap) fonts are used. Which TeX distribution do you use? On which OS? Which command do you use to get PDF from TeX source? Which languages are used in your document?

Comment: @Joseph, @kemiisto: You can see which fonts are used in a Postscript/Pdf file from Acrobat Reader, in the document properties viewer.  But I wouldn't call type 3 fonts "dim".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't like Computer Modern Roman?  Try a different type, like Palatino.  You can vary the number points of the type to give it a heavier feel, say by using 12pt fonts.

Otherwise, I agree with noviceoof, everything with your .tex file looks perfectly standard.  It's just about possible that Latex's font path is finding fonts you don't like, but I would try different fonts before testing this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try different document classes (book, report, letter). What do you mean with "coming too dim"?

Have a look at

http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/schmidt/schmidt.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change your font, check out http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/
LaTeX actually has quite a few nice fonts :P

Comment: +1 I didn't know of this.  That's really nice and well thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have installed cm-super package. Without it Computer Modern font looks dim in output pdf.